# how to pass the parameter value from the php page

Tags: php, mysql

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `users` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `users`(in id int(25))
BEGIN

    declare empcode varchar(25);

    set empcode=(select emp_code from transaction_user_register where t_reg_id=id);

    delete from transaction_user_register where t_reg_id=id and emp_code=empcode;

    update user_register set active='2' where reg_id=id and emp_code=empcode;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

how to pass the id from php page....

i call the procedure from the php page
i don't know how to pass the parameter value...

i write the page like

```
<? require_once"db.php";
echo $id = $_REQUEST['t_reg_id'];

$connt = mysql_connect($server1, $user1, $pass1, $dbname1) or die ("__construct() Function Problem => ". mysqli_error());
$resr= mysql_query($connt,"CALL users('$id')"); 
mysql_close($connt);




echo "Cron Job Run Succesfully........";

?>
```

Comment: by sending like this, are you getting any error?

Comment: just an advise, you shouldnt take `$_REQUEST[]` values and using them directly in your `mysqli_query`, I believe thats a security risk

Comment: i dont know how to pass the id value

Comment: You can use functions like `intval()` to cast it to int and then use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to make it a bit secure

Answer (score 0):

Since you're utilizing `mysqli` use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of interpolating query strings, which leaves your code wide open to sql injections.

That being said your code might look something like

```php
<?php
require_once('db.php');
$id = $_REQUEST['t_reg_id'];

$db = new mysqli($server1, $user1, $pass1, $dbname1);
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $db->connect_error);
}
$stmt = $db->prepare('CALL users(?)');
if (!$stmt) {
    die('Prepare failed: ' . $db->error); 
}
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id); // that's assuming id is an integer value
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die('Execute failed: ' . $db->error);
}
$stmt->close()
$db->close();

...
```

Comment: i am use mysql not mysqli

Comment: You're a bit confused. You're using MySQL server, but at the same time you're using [`mysqli_*`](http://lt1.php.net/mysqli) (`mysqli_connect()`, `mysqli_query`, ...) php extension to access data

Comment: by mistake i put mysqli.

Comment: **Don't use `mysql_*`** extension. It's deprecated. Use `mysqli` and prepared statements as showed in the answer.